# SELECT and UPDATE at the same time

Tags: mysql, transactions

I need to export some data to a CSV file. To do this, I issue a `SELECT` command of those rows with a certain column set to 0. After that, I must set those rows to 1 in order to not export them again.

What is the best approach to face this situation? I mean some "transaction" where I `UPDATE` the exact same rows that I selected before.

Is `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` the way to go?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it helps to anyone, what I did was having a 3 state field in my table.

Every time a record is inserted, its' initial state is 0.

The following occurs inside a transaction when I want to export new rows:

- Those with state 0 (new) are set to 1 (about to be exported)
- Select rows with state 1 (about to be exported) for csv export
- Those with state 1 (about to be exported) are set to 2 (exported)

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
UPDATE table SET column = 1 WHERE(
SELECT column FROM table WHERE column = 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

This question is probably old but may help someone in future searching for same thing. Simple answer **NO!**. There is no way to select and Update at same time in MySQL. Though as per your question you can make **Stored Procedure** like this

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `GetandUpdate` (IN IDSet VARCHAR(300)
BEGIN
    select * from tbl_CSV where state = 0 and FIND_IN_SET(id, IDSet);
    update tbl_CSV set state = 1 where state = 0 and FIND_IN_SET(id, IDSet);
END
```

where IDSet can be an comma seperated string like *3,14,8,1*